# 2006 Cadillac DTS no crank no start everything else powers up

Tags: starting, no-crank-no-start, cadillac

2006 Cadillac DTS 4.6L Northstar engine no crank no start fuel pump also does not come on check relays and fuses everything else works

Comment: Check for loose battery cables.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You sure this isn't a security thing?

Comment: That sounds similar to the symptoms produced by a faulty neutral safety switch, although in my experience the fuel pump still runs when the neutral safety switch is engaged.